# Replace url in ui-router (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, angular-ui-router

I have an application that uses angularjs and ui-router for routing.

One of my urls is:
http://www.nadpco.com/#/NewsDetails?cat=4&id=2871

In some another where, my url will be like this:

[http://www.nadpco.com/#/NewsDetails?cat=4&amp;id=2871](http://www.nadpco.com/#/NewsDetails?cat=4&id=2871)

Note that **&amp;** is added to second url.

Now I want when user clicks the second url, ui-router, route to correct url.

How can I do this.

Thanks.

Comment: in some another means.?

Comment: this is already being done when we click on both the urls, same page is being displayed..then where is the problem

Comment: Please copy second url and paste it in browser address bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$location** service to do so.

Refer to link:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location